# How to pass json string in get parameter via curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I have been trying to send JSON Data in Get Request VIA CURL in PHP.
Tried to add slashes decode encode string to JSON but failed cannot output the exact string as I want it to be,
Here is an example how I want PHP to return string:

```
http://example.com/android/napp/session.php?session={"session_key":"5.T1lJSZI3WsHvFg.1508724894.24-100021584769980","uid":100021584769980,"secret":"2c3ebc8254d355e3466b17355ca2c6b5","access_token":"EAAAAUaZA8jlABAKbUNcsBEf0HkaCzDnUnbCHQmAQLIFTtCNKlA6SDAZCMNMVp7JV3ZBYjpMfePC0mBconu4L6syQSMXthrOGpKYXZBQ9BzEprfj8wfvAkI3Cy373ZAuCCi7MS78TDbo17XYZBmZCBxjVrYS4pXh9aneODkwfy0Ek5RvA2tPVr0r10myGZC078EwZD","machine_id":"nlDtWb6yQQFtpBnjEmwbdzBZ","session_cookies":[{"name":"c_user","value":"100021584769980","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"24:T1lJSZI3WsHvFg:2:1508724894:13272:7254","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"0wOwW7rSJ6acRLZJY.AWUeoVqBbkRqh1YVP6sjD6-ynRM.BZ7VCe..AAA.0.0.BZ7VCe.AWXGSMmw","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"nlDtWb6yQQFtpBnjEmwbdzBZ","expires":"Wed, 23 Oct 2019 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1571796894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true}],"identifier":"whatever.pro","user_storage_key":"0f4194ede822da3b281a83fb18e2953df075d97c792d1697024346ca8bca53c3"}
```

While I tried to use it in curl but its adding slashes 
as I called it this way:

```
post_data('http://example.com/android/napp/session.php?session={"session_key":"5.T1lJSZI3WsHvFg.1508724894.24-100021584769980","uid":100021584769980,"secret":"2c3ebc8254d355e3466b17355ca2c6b5","access_token":"EAAAAUaZA8jlABAKbUNcsBEf0HkaCzDnUnbCHQmAQLIFTtCNKlA6SDAZCMNMVp7JV3ZBYjpMfePC0mBconu4L6syQSMXthrOGpKYXZBQ9BzEprfj8wfvAkI3Cy373ZAuCCi7MS78TDbo17XYZBmZCBxjVrYS4pXh9aneODkwfy0Ek5RvA2tPVr0r10myGZC078EwZD","machine_id":"nlDtWb6yQQFtpBnjEmwbdzBZ","session_cookies":[{"name":"c_user","value":"100021584769980","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"24:T1lJSZI3WsHvFg:2:1508724894:13272:7254","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"0wOwW7rSJ6acRLZJY.AWUeoVqBbkRqh1YVP6sjD6-ynRM.BZ7VCe..AAA.0.0.BZ7VCe.AWXGSMmw","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"nlDtWb6yQQFtpBnjEmwbdzBZ","expires":"Wed, 23 Oct 2019 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1571796894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true}],"identifier":"whatever.pro","user_storage_key":"0f4194ede822da3b281a83fb18e2953df075d97c792d1697024346ca8bca53c3"}','');
```

I tried using stripslashes method but failed.

My CURL Function is here:

```
function post_data($url, $fields) {

    $cookies = dirname(__FILE__).
    '/cookie.txt';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, getRandomUserAgent());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $redir = $info['redirect_url'];
        $code = $info['http_code'];
        curl_close($ch);
        return "<br>".$body;


    }
}
```

Comment: `stripslashes()`

Comment: Looks like you are calling `post_data()` without its second parameter. Also, why are you hardcoding JSON strings instead of encoding the data using the according functions? That said, I'd use POST and put the JSON content into the body, I think cURL even offers a utility function for that.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt that's because the receiving server isnt mine and they want it to be in the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using urlencode() on your json data, so:

```
$urlencoded = urlencode('{"session_key":"5.T1lJSZI3WsHvFg.1508724894.24-100021584769980","uid":100021584769980,"secret":"2c3ebc8254d355e3466b17355ca2c6b5","access_token":"EAAAAUaZA8jlABAKbUNcsBEf0HkaCzDnUnbCHQmAQLIFTtCNKlA6SDAZCMNMVp7JV3ZBYjpMfePC0mBconu4L6syQSMXthrOGpKYXZBQ9BzEprfj8wfvAkI3Cy373ZAuCCi7MS78TDbo17XYZBmZCBxjVrYS4pXh9aneODkwfy0Ek5RvA2tPVr0r10myGZC078EwZD","machine_id":"nlDtWb6yQQFtpBnjEmwbdzBZ","session_cookies":[{"name":"c_user","value":"100021584769980","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"\/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"24:T1lJSZI3WsHvFg:2:1508724894:13272:7254","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"0wOwW7rSJ6acRLZJY.AWUeoVqBbkRqh1YVP6sjD6-ynRM.BZ7VCe..AAA.0.0.BZ7VCe.AWXGSMmw","expires":"Tue, 23 Oct 2018 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1540260894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"nlDtWb6yQQFtpBnjEmwbdzBZ","expires":"Wed, 23 Oct 2019 02:14:54 GMT","expires_timestamp":1571796894,"domain":".website.com","path":"\/","secure":true,"httponly":true}],"identifier":"whatever.pro","user_storage_key":"0f4194ede822da3b281a83fb18e2953df075d97c792d1697024346ca8bca53c3"}');

post_date('http://example.com/android/napp/session.php?session=' . $urlencoded);
```

Comment: Didnt helped cause the source website dont want it encoded they want it to be in the exact format i cant modify the source website

Comment: The issue is that some of those characters create a malformed URL, the only way would be to encode value of that field. The server on the other end is 99% going to be url decoding the parameters in anycase. For example, if the server is using a framework like CakePHP or Laravel, this decoding would happen in the background without the developer needing to action any changes on the server side.

Comment: You are obligated to encode your parameter. The server on the other side will decode it on their own, thus creating a string that can be converted into an object on the receiving server side.

Comment: @MarkMenzies It has to be but it doesn't. Know why but its not accepting it while I am trying to do it manually it works.

Comment: Worked now That's great. it wasn't working yesterday but today. :)